# How to do I get the max day of each month in sql/snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I’m trying to return The max day of each month from a data set. I say max because it’s based on mon-fri uploads. So if the last day of the month falls on a Saturday(say 10/31/2019) then the last uploaded date will be on the Friday (10/30/2019).

I’ve tried select max(date) from my_table group by datepart(‘month’,date);

Comment: What is wrong with your current query? Please show us sample data and expected results.

Comment: I agree with @GMB, your query looks perfectly fine, so the problem must lie in the parts that you have not disclosed...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dayofweekiso` to get only those `monday-friday` transactions.

```
select max(date), month(case when date) from my_table 
where dayofweekiso(date) between 1 and 5
group by year(date), month(date);
```

Comment: Not even sure the WHERE clause is necessary here.  There won't be any data with dates on saturday or sunday, if I understand the question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Using the snowflake_sample_date there is a date dimension, Small change to MIkes query .. 1--7 looks good

SELECT
      MAX(d.d_date)
  FROM
      tpcds_sf10tcl.date_dim d
  WHERE    DAYOFWEEKISO(d.d_date) BETWEEN 1 AND 7
  GROUP BY
      YEAR(d.d_date)
      , MONTH(d.d_date)
  ORDER BY
      MAX(d_date);

Answer (score 0):

[QUALIFY](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html) can be used to create a rank and filter on it on the fly. So rank on partition by year and month, order by date descending to rank the last days of each month in your table as 1.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
QUALIFY RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(DATE), MONTH(DATE) ORDER BY DATE DESC) = 1;
```